# Remote desktop: Ubuntu 12.04 from Windows 7

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, desktop-sharing

I want to share(and give control of) my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop to my brother(using Windows 7).
We are not on the same network. (We're in different cities).

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this (without compromising security)?
I read that VNC isn't very secure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try Teamviewer. Nice tool, i've often used it private and at work to remote access PCs. With Teamviewer it's also possible to access clients via Android/IPhone.

Comment: uhh, i forgot... there is also a possibility to use the web interface to access clients. that's also a very nice feature, I think!

Answer (score 0):

You can also user UltraVNC. It works good with Windows-Linux remote desktop. [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/downloads/ultravnc.html)